# How to find the highest value of a column in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, max

I have the following data frame which I called ozone:

```
   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1     41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2     36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3     12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4     18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5     NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
6     28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
7     23     299  8.6   65     5   7
8     19      99 13.8   59     5   8
9      8      19 20.1   61     5   9
```

I would like to extract the highest value from `ozone`, `Solar.R`, `Wind`...

Also, if possible how would I sort `Solar.R` or any column of this data frame in descending order

I tried

```
max(ozone, na.rm=T)
```

which gives me the highest value in the dataset.

I have also tried

```
max(subset(ozone,Ozone))
```

but got `"subset" must be logical."`

I can set an object to hold the subset of each column, by the following commands

```
ozone <- subset(ozone, Ozone >0)
max(ozone,na.rm=T)
```

but it gives the same value of 334, which is the max value of the data frame, not the column.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: `max(ozone$Ozone)` or `max(subset(ozone,select=Ozone))`. You should definitely look at some introductory R material on column indexing for data frames, which is your basic trouble. (This is a coursera question, right? https://github.com/ahawker/data-analysis-coursera/blob/master/HW1/hw1.R )

Comment: @BenBolker Yes it is. btw how did you gray sections of your comment.

Comment: I used backticks `` (I'm sure there's formatting help around here somewhere?)

Comment: Thanks! I am following you on github, btw the name of the course is now [R Programming](https://www.coursera.org/course/rprog). It's part of the ["Data Specialization Track"](https://www.coursera.org/specialization/jhudatascience/1?utm_medium=courseDescripTop)

Comment: @BenBolker: Here's a [link to SO comment formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) - always available by clicking the "help" link beside the comment box.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Similar to `colMeans`, `colSums`, etc, you could write a column maximum function, `colMax`, and a column sort function, `colSort`.

```
colMax <- function(data) sapply(data, max, na.rm = TRUE)
colSort <- function(data, ...) sapply(data, sort, ...)
```

I use `...` in the second function in hopes of sparking your intrigue.

Get your data:

```
dat <- read.table(h=T, text = "Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1     41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2     36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3     12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4     18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5     NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
6     28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
7     23     299  8.6   65     5   7
8     19      99 13.8   59     5   8
9      8      19 20.1   61     5   9")
```

Use `colMax` function on sample data:

```
colMax(dat)
#  Ozone Solar.R    Wind    Temp   Month     Day 
#   41.0   313.0    20.1    74.0     5.0     9.0
```

To do the sorting on a single column,

```
sort(dat$Solar.R, decreasing = TRUE)
# [1] 313 299 190 149 118  99  19
```

and over all columns use our `colSort` function,

```
colSort(dat, decreasing = TRUE) ## compare with '...' above
```

Comment: Coerces your ints to nums, so `lapply` might be preferable.

Comment: @Frank - right you are.  I'm not really doing much around here any more.  Feel free to edit and I will make it a community wiki

Answer (score 51):

To get the max of any column you want something like:

```
max(ozone$Ozone, na.rm = TRUE)
```

To get the max of all columns, you want:

```
apply(ozone, 2, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

And to sort:

```
ozone[order(ozone$Solar.R),]
```

Or to sort the other direction:

```
ozone[rev(order(ozone$Solar.R)),]
```

Comment: To get the max of all columns , it can also be: `apply(ozone, 2, max, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

# find max for each column
summarise_each(ozone, funs(max(., na.rm=TRUE)))

# sort by Solar.R, descending
arrange(ozone, desc(Solar.R))
```

**UPDATE:** `summarise_each()` has been deprecated in favour of a more featureful family of functions: `mutate_all()`, `mutate_at()`, `mutate_if()`, `summarise_all()`, `summarise_at()`, `summarise_if()`

Here is how you could do:

```
# find max for each column
ozone %>%
         summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(max(., na.rm=TRUE)))%>%
         arrange(Ozone)
```

or

```
ozone %>%
         summarise_at(vars(1:6), funs(max(., na.rm=TRUE)))%>%
         arrange(Ozone)
```

Comment: **For newer R version**. If you encounter a warning message:
`funs()` is deprecated as of dplyr 0.8.0.
Please use a list of either functions or lambdas: The following lambda code worked for me: `ozone %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, list(~ max(., na.rm=TRUE)))`

Answer (score 7):

In response to finding the max value for each column, you could try using the `apply()` function:

```
> apply(ozone, MARGIN = 2, function(x) max(x, na.rm=TRUE))
  Ozone Solar.R    Wind    Temp   Month     Day 
   41.0   313.0    20.1    74.0     5.0     9.0
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's going on here?

Comment: Of course, please enter `?apply` in your console to follow along. The function has the following arguments: `apply(X, MARGIN, FUN, ...)`. `X` refers to your array or, in this case, data frame. `MARGIN` specifies how you want the function to be applied to your data frame. For instance, `1` indicates rows while `2` is for columns. `FUN` is the function you wish to apply over your selected `MARGIN`. The above answer creates a user-defined function that finds the max value while disregarding NA values. In brief, the answer locates the max value in each column of your data frame while ignoring NAs.

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to use ?pmax

```
do.call('pmax', c(as.data.frame(t(ozone)),na.rm=TRUE))
#[1]  41.0 313.0  20.1  74.0   5.0   9.0
```

Comment: This is neat (+1), but its worth noting that converting to "matrix" and, then, back to "data.frame" is slow and `pmax` loses its speed advantage. (`apply` is slower on a "data.frame", too, for the same reason). E.g. `DF = as.data.frame(matrix(sample(100, 1e6, T), 1e2, 1e4))` ; `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sapply(DF, max), do.call(pmax, as.data.frame(t(DF))), apply(DF, 2, max), unlist(lapply(DF, max)), as.matrix(DF), as.data.frame(t(DF)), times = 20)`. P.S. Sorry, for the long (and partly irrelevant) comment here, but I do like `pmax` :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a package `matrixStats` that provides some functions to do column and row summaries, see in the package [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matrixStats/vignettes/matrixStats-methods.html), but you have to convert your data.frame into a matrix.

Then you run: `colMaxs(as.matrix(ozone))`

Answer (score 2):

```
max(may$Ozone, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Without `$Ozone` it will filter in the whole data frame, this can be learned in the swirl library.

I'm studying this course on Coursera too ~

Answer (score 1):

`max(ozone$Ozone, na.rm = TRUE)` should do the trick. Remember to include the `na.rm = TRUE` or else R will return NA.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data in `data.frame` called `maxinozone`, you can do this

```
max(maxinozone[1, ], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
Oz<-subset(data, data$Month==5,select=Ozone) # select ozone  value in the month of                 
                                             #May (i.e. Month = 5)
summary(T)                                   #gives caracteristics of table( contains 1 column of Ozone) including max, min ...
```