# Find the maximum and minimum value of every column and then find the maximum and minimum value of every row

Tags: r, matrix, max, minimum

I've got this matrix:

```
a <- matrix(rnorm(1000 * 18, mean = 100, sd = sqrt(10)), 1000, 18)
```

I would like to find the maximum and minimum value of every column and the maximum and minimum value of every row.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Figured it out.

Minimum and maximum of every column:

```
apply(a,2,min)
apply(a,2,max)
```

Minimum and maximum of every row:

```
apply(a,1,min)
apply(a,1,max)
```

Found the information here http://www.personality-project.org/r/r.commands.html

Comment: how could I add `na.rm = TRUE`?

Comment: `apply(a,2,min, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
apply(a, 1, range)
```

Using this together with `t`, this gives you two columns. The first one with the minimum the second with the maximum of the rows.

```
head(t(apply(a, 1, range)))
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 95.75922 103.6956
[2,] 93.62636 106.3934
[3,] 92.70567 106.9190
[4,] 96.53577 104.4971
[5,] 96.61573 107.6691
[6,] 95.56239 105.5887
```

for the column maxima change 1 to 2 in the apply function.

Answer (score 5):

See the `matrixStats` package. You can use `colMins()`, `rowMaxs()` and functions like this both for columns and rows.

See this answer: [How to find the highest value of a column in a data frame in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212739/how-to-find-the-highest-value-of-a-column-in-a-data-frame-in-r/39750306#39750306)

Answer (score 1):

A faster alternative for row max/min would be using `pmax()` and `pmin()` even though you would first have to convert the matrix to a list (data.frame is a special case of a list):

```
apply(a,1,min)
apply(a,1,max)
# becomes
do.call(pmin, as.data.frame(a))
do.call(pmax, as.data.frame(a))
```

For the columns it will be less "competitive" because of having to transpose first:

```
apply(a,2,min)
apply(a,2,max)
# becomes
do.call(pmin, as.data.frame(t(a)))
do.call(pmin, as.data.frame(t(a)))
```

**Benchmarking**:

```
a <- matrix(rnorm(1000 * 18 *10, mean = 100, sd = sqrt(10)), 1000 * 10, 18 * 10)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  do.call(pmin, as.data.frame(a)),
  apply(a,1,min),
  unit = "relative"
)
                            expr      min     lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
 do.call(pmin, as.data.frame(a)) 1.000000 1.0000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000   100
                apply(a, 1, min) 2.281095 2.3576 2.096402 2.531092 2.618693 0.6284233   100
```

Comment: Apparently there is slightly faster but uglier version: `do.call(pmin, lapply(seq_len(ncol(a)), function(i) a[, i]))`