# How to take a data.frame and create a table of only the Max values?

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:
[image]

I would like to create a table of the column headers, in a column with their maximum value to the right of them.  I will be looking to embed this in a `Shiny` App.  Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I used:

`colMax <- function(data) sapply(data, max, na.rm=TRUE)`

Then I called `as.data.frame(colmax(data))` and it worked as needed.

Duplicate: [How to find the highest value of a column in a data frame in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212739/how-to-find-the-highest-value-of-a-column-in-a-data-frame-in-r)