# obtaining max value in each column and printing associated column and row name

Tags: r

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212739/how-to-find-the-highest-value-of-a-column-in-a-data-frame-in-r/24212879) got me started, but I haven't been able to manipulate the expression to sufficiently generate the desired output. As a simplified version of the file contents, let's say I create the following matrix in R:

```
set.seed(14)
B = matrix(sample(1:100, 9),
      nrow=3,
      ncol=3)

colnames(B) <- c("sam1", "sam2", "sam3")
rownames(B) <- c("obs1", "obs2", "obs3")
```

It should look something like this:

```
        sam1    sam2    sam3
obs1    26      54      88
obs2    64      95      40 
obs3    94      49      45
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to loop through this matrix to calculate the maximum value in each column, then print out a new file which incorporates the value as well as the row name and column name. Thus the desired output would be a new file structured as follows:

```
sam1    94    obs3
sam2    95    obs2
sam3    88    obs1
```

If it helps, the file itself need not be a matrix. Rather, it could also be structured as a simple .csv file where `obs` are themselves are the first column (rather than rowname), and `sam` are elements across the first row (less the first column).

Thank you for your consideration

Comment: Am sorry, I just checked and realized I used `rows` instead of `columns`. I have edited the work and it is now good for the task

Answer (score 1):

```
data.frame(w=colnames(B),x=B[cbind(n<-max.col(B),1:ncol(B))],y=rownames(B)[n])
     w  x    y
1 sam1 94 obs3
2 sam2 95 obs2
3 sam3 88 obs1
```

Comment: Really nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

@Onyambu beat me to the punch but here is my solution using apply:

```
C <- data.frame(row.names = colnames(B),
                    MaxVal = apply(B, 2, max),
                    WhichMax = apply(B, 2, which.max))
C
     MaxVal WhichMax
sam1     94        3
sam2     95        2
sam3     88        1
```

Comment: Thanks to both @Onyambu and JonGrub. Both solutions worked for my toy example provided here. Curiously I received an error with Onymabu's solution when I used my real data (not this toy example):

    Error in reads.mat[cbind(n <- max.col(reads.mat), seq(nrow(reads.mat)))] : subscript out of bounds
    
In the case of JonGrub's solution my real data prints without error, but the data.frame produced prints the number of the list (3, 2, 1 in the toy example); the intention was to print the name itself. Nevertheless, this solution works, and a bit more data wrangling gets me through.

Answer (score 0):

with data.table you could do:

```
library(data.table)
B <- setDT(as.data.frame(B))
B[,name := c("obs1", "obs2", "obs3")]
```

B loks like

```
   sam1 sam2 sam3 name
1:   26   54   88 obs1
2:   64   95   40 obs2
3:   94   49   45 obs3
```

Then you simply melt and take the max value for each variable group

```
melt(B)[,.SD[value == max(value),.(value,name)],by = variable]

   variable value name
1:     sam1    94 obs3
2:     sam2    95 obs2
3:     sam3    88 obs1
```